# Contact form module for different users

Tags: 7, emails

I am looking for a contact form module for different users logged in to the website.

E.g.,

1) a website that has different authors

2) the user clicks on the author's page there is a contact form for that specific author on their page

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Have you looked at the contact form module that is part of the core? It seems to fulfill your requirements. And if that does not do what you want, please explain what extra features you're looking for.

Comment: Can the contact forum module send out to specific users? And not just the default user? And can this be embedded on a specific user page?

Comment: Yes, yes, and almost - it is not *embedded* in the page, but it put's a "Contact" tab on the user's page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the *core contact form* for this.

Basic documentation about setting it up can be found in the [user contributed documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/124129) on Drupal.org.

The contact form let you have a site contact form (sent to the default user), and a contact form tied to each individual user. When you enable the latter option, a tab "Contact" will appear when someone visit's that user's page (provided they're permitted to see it).

Individual users may disable other's access to their contact form, but the administrator may override this.

The core contact form can be configured through options and permissions.  It is very flexible, but it may take some tuning to get the exact behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

The [Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) and [Message Private](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_private) allow your site's visitors to send private messages to each other. Using these modules you can allow users to send private messages to the authors.

you can also use [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module.

> Webform is the module for making surveys in Drupal. After a submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic statistical review and has and extensive API for expanding its features.

In this module you can add an `author` field which lists all of the authors and on every author page, only displays its name. using `hook_form_alter` you can set the current author as the value of the `author` field.

As another solution, You can create a unique form for every author, in this way you can configure the form for every author (including unique email address).

It is easy to display different webforms in authors page. The following code loads and displays a webform with `client-block-852` id

```
<?php 
    $block = module_invoke('webform','block_view' ,'client-block-852');
    print render($block['content']);
?>
```

so in `hook_preprocess_page` check for the current page (using url or anything else) if it is an author page, loads its appropriate webform.